# FileWriter and InputStream in java

Tags: java, java-io

Before, when I used file in my fileWriter it worked, but now, since I'm using getResourceAsStream instead of file, how can I make it work?

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(new File("filename"), true);
```

Now, when I pass

```
InputStream is = getResourceAsStream("filename");
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(is, true);
```

I had to change it, because when I create a runnable jar with the maven assembly plugin there is no src/main/resources in the jar

**EDIT:**

thanks to casablanca and others for pointing out my mistakes, follow up :

I need to write to a file, but append to it, with preserving the original content. And I need to know to which file I'm writing of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InputStream` represents an input stream, so it is not suitable as ouput. You cannot write to an `Inputstream`. `getResourceAsStream` return a stream for *reading* a resource, not for writing to it.

I'm affraid there is no easy way to write to resource loaded via the `ClassLoader`. One solution would be to read it as [`Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), and then use the `store` method to write it to a resource file, obtaining the output stream by other means. You can obtain the URI of the resource file using the classloader, but there is no guarantee you can write to it directly (for example if it is bundled in a signed jar).

Comment: I could figure out that but which class should I use to get resource for writting?

Comment: If you really want to write to a file, obtain the URI of the resource, using [findResource](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResource(java.lang.String)), and write to it.

Comment: +1 for further explanation, when I try getClass.getClassLoader().findResouce("/Myfile.txt"); again I get compile error like findResource doesn't exist, what about this?

Comment: Well, my bad. In fact, `findResource` is protected, and you should use [`getResource`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to write to a stream, you need a generic stream writer, not a file writer. Secondly, writing means output, so you need an output writer. So the class you're looking for is [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html).

`getResourceAsStream` returns an `InputStream` which you can only use for *reading*, which means you can only use a class such as [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

**Update:**

You already have the correct code for appending to a file, using `FileWriter`. However, `getResourceAsStream` returns a read-only resource, so there is no straightforward method to write data back to it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what should I give to OutputStreamWritter(obviously OutputStream), where do I get it from? does this support appending file?I need to append file without removing the original contents.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the docu, [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), you will see, that there is no constructor for your InputStream. Thats why i does not compile. Since you did not ask anything, thats it.

Comment: forgot to ask, how can I get OutputStream? to use for OutputStreamWritter?